# using woocommerce api locally

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, localhost, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm creating a wordpress plugin that communicates with woocommerce installed on the same wordpress site. I noticed that the rest api requires ssl to use, but it seems like ssl locally is not possible and oauth is a pain in the ass.

Is there a way to develop for woocommerce locally without having ssl that doesn't use oauth?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend beginning by throwing out the idea of calling back to a local site over any HTTP/S protocol. That is almost never the right decision.

Instead, woocommerce has extended the WordPress hook/filter system into themselves: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/. This allows you to inject/extend yourself throughout woocommerce without making a cludgy callback system. I don't know what you want/need to do, but I can guarantee the hooks should probably get you all the functionality you will need.

If you truly do need to make API calls back. You basically won't be able to develop locally (without a lot of effort setting up a local server environment). Instead set up a development environment on a separate server.

---

*I assumed this is a mostly php plugin running on the server. If instead this will be serving a lot of javascript to the frontend, then you will **have** to use the REST API, and you will have to get some development server up with ssl.*

---

**Update:** based on comment below expounding on purpose. I assume you figured out to add the 'sales goal' information as post meta to the woocommerce product. Here's a quick introduction to post meta if you need it: https://dsgnwrks.pro/how-to/what-is-post-meta-an-intro-to-wordpress-custom-fields/. This would be the best practice for adding information to the products.

For the proportion of sales to the goal. You will first need a function to get the total sales to date on this product. Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/kloon/6238672) that hooks into `woocommerce_single_product_summary` and gets the post_meta `total_sales` on the current product. You should be able to use a similar scheme to get both `total_sales` and your `sales_goal` post meta and then just display the ratio in whatever way you choose.

Note: You may need to attach to a different hook. Or you may even need to get the current product a different way (maybe specified by the widget?) to get ahold of the post_meta.

Comment: so what I'm trying to do is create a widget that takes the total sales from a particular product and base that total against a goal. so in the admin widget area: you would select an item, enter a goal amount and on the front-end of the site you would see if the sales from that item are close to your goal

Comment: so really I need to return all past orders for that product

Comment: woocommerce products have a post_meta value `total_sales` that should work for you. See updated answer.

Comment: from what I understand hooks are callbacks that happen when something is executed in woocommerce (similar to an event), and `woocommerce_single_product_summary ` is called when viewing that item from within a woocommerce controlled page/area but this plugin can live on any page and should be able to display this data at any time. please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like hooks/fliters may not be right for this.
this plugin would have access to that data at any time. the goal amount is a part of the widget's metadata

Comment: My mistake. To have it all contained in the widget to display anywhere then, the widget will need to have both the goal and the relevant product. A simple call to `get_post_meta` for the `total_sales` meta value with the widgets product should get the information you need.